# How to run helm from a docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

We use a helm container in our CI environment to execute our helm commands and it works swimmingly.  I am trying to replicate that success running helm from a container locally and not having much luck.  I'm 99% sure it's a config issue, but I haven't been able to find any thing on the Internet specific to this situation.  Here's the snippet docker command from my script.  I've been testing with `ls` as the argument:

```
  docker run \
      -v $(pwd):/apps \
      -v "${HOME}/.kube:/root/.kube" \
      -v "${HOME}/.helm:/root/.helm" \
      -e KUBECONFIG=${HOME}/foo/kubeconfig \
      -it \
      -w "$(pwd)" \
      -ti \
      docker-dev.foo.com/bar/bat/helm helm "$@"
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

If I do a `helm ls` locally, everything works just fine which is why I believe this is a config issue.

Comment: make sure to use proper network because when you are calling `127.0.0.1:8080` from the container, it most certainly doesn't have anything running on that port inside of it

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: If you're seeing Kubernetes trying to connect to `localhost:8080` it probably means it can't find the `$HOME/.kube/config` file; that's a default value that often isn't correct.

Comment: @edbighead, I will check test that out tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @DavidMaze, that would be odd because I confirmed that all three volume mounts are accessible in the running container and contain the data from my host system.  Does helm spin up a new container and then try to connect to that, by chance?  If so, I could totally see `connection refused` happening because nothing is running on localhost in the container.

Comment: @edbighead unfortunately, that didn't work.  I'm not running anything on my host so there's nothing to map.  My current theory is that `helm ls` tries to spin up a new container running on `:8080` and connect to it, but I don't know helm well enough to know for sure.

Comment: Looking at the command again, you're setting `-e KUBECONFIG=...` to your host-system path, but also `-v` bind-mounting it to `/root/.kube` in the container.  Those need to match.

Comment: @DavidMaze that's a great point.  I volume mounted that folder from my host into the container and confirmed it's visible and has the kubeconfig, but still the same error.  I might need to move on from this and find another way.